# PowerShell Filtering the Output of Remote Desktop Users Group

Tags: powershell

Utilizing PowerShell I'm trying to get a list of users/group which have Remote Desktop User permissions to be able to log onto a Server.

I can utilise "*net localgroup"* to get a list of the groups/users with Remote Desktop User Permissions:

> PS C:\Users\pal.test> net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" Alias name
>   Remote Desktop Users Comment        Members in this group are granted
>   the right to logon remotely
>
> Members
>
> ---
>
> PAL\kron.pal
>   PAL\PAL-VPN-Clients
>   The command completed successfully.

However if I run this command and output to a variable I get all the headings included:

> PS C:\Users\pal.test> $RDPUsers = net localgroup "Remote Desktop
>   Users"
>
> PS C:\Users\pal.test> write-host $RDPUsers
>
> Alias name     Remote Desktop Users Comment        Members in this
>   group are granted the right to logon remotely  Member s 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PAL\kron.pal PAL\PAL-VPN-Client
>   The command completed successfully.

For other commands like "*Get-WMIObject*" I would utilise "*| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members* to filter the property and select only the property values. However if I use this get either a blank output or an error when I try to use -ExpandProperty:

> PS C:\Users\pal.test> net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members
>
> Select-Object : Property "Members" cannot be found.
>
> At line:1 char:41
>
> - net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Alias name     Remote Desktop Users:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
>
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
>   ```

Is there a better way to list the users/groups in Windows Server 2008/2012/2016 than using "*net localgroup*"?

If not how do you filter the output of "*net localgroup*"?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and [format the code as code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)? Thanks.

Comment: For Windows Server 2016 you could use [Get-LocalGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroup?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Thanks Olaf the "Get-LocalGroup" works on Windows Server 2016 however the cmdlet doesn't appear to be available in Windows Server 2008 and 2012. I get a "is not the name of a recognised cmdlet". I'll user the Windows version to create an if statement and use the "Get-LocalGroup" for Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Anyone know of any other options for Windows Server 2008 and 2012? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lee_Dailey; your solution was very close to what I needed. I found however that PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 2008 doesn't have the 'skiplast' option as part of the "Select-Object" option.

I did use your code as the basis of alternative solution to avoid the 'skiplast' option no being available in PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 2008.

```
PS C:\Users\pal.test> net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" | where {$_ -AND $_ -notmatch "command completed successfully"} | select -skip 4
PAL\kron.pal
PAL\PAL-VPN-Client
```

Answer (score 1):

This too is untested by me on Server 2008/2012/2016 but it may help:

```
function Get-LocalGroupMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [String]$Identity,
        [String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement 
    $context = New-Object DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('Machine', $ComputerName)

    try {
        if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Identity))) {
            # search a specific group
            [DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $Identity)
        }
        else {
            # search all local groups
            $groupPrincipal    = New-Object DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal($context)
            $principalSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher($groupPrincipal)
        }
    }
    catch {
        throw "Error searching group(s) on '$ComputerName'. $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    finally {
        if ($groupPrincipal)    {$groupPrincipal.Dispose()}
        if ($principalSearcher) {$principalSearcher.FindAll()}
    }
}

(Get-LocalGroupMembers -Identity "Remote Desktop Users").Members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

With the above function you will get objects returned with various properties. 
In this example I selected only the Name property. If you want to look at all properties, just remove the `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Answer (score 0):

i THINK this will work on 2008, but cannot test it. [*blush*]

```
$NET_LocalGroupInfo = net localgroup users |
    Select-Object -Skip 6 |
    Select-Object -SkipLast 2 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Trim()
        }

$NET_LocalGroupInfo
```

i don't know when the `-Skip*` parameters were added. if that fails on your target systems, try using array indexing to get only the ones you want.